# Error in recursive function with Numba in nopython mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples, numba

I want to run a recursive function in Numba, using nopython mode. Until now I'm only getting errors. This is a very simple code, the user gives a tuple with less than five elements and then the function creates another tuple with a new value added to the tuple (in this case, the number 3). This is repeated until the final tuple has length 5. For some reason this is not working, don't know why.

```py
@njit
def tup(a):
    if len(a) == 5:
        return a
    else:
        b = a + (3,)
        b = tup(b)
        return b
```

For example, if `a = (0,1)`, I would expect the final result to be tuple `(0,1,3,3,3)`.

EDIT: I'm using Numba 0.41.0 and the error I'm getting is the kernel dying, 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'

Comment: Please don't forget to show what kind of errors you get. Including the numba version could also be helpful because numba is still in active development and the set of supported functionality is moving at a fast pace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons why you shouldn't do that:

- This is generally a kind of approach that will likely be faster in pure Python than in a numba-decorated function.
- Iteration will be simpler and probably faster, however beware that concatenating tuples is generally an `O(n)` operation, even in numba. So the overall performance of the function will be `O(n**2)`. This can be improved by using a data-structure that supports `O(1)` appends or a data-structure that supports pre-allocating the size. Or simply by not using a "loopy" or "recursive" approach.
- Have you tried what happens if you leave out the `njit` decorator and pass in a tuple that contains 6 elements? (hint: it will hit the recursion limit because it never fulfills the end condition of the recursion).

Numba, at the time of writing 0.43.1, only supports simple recursions when the type of the arguments don't change between recursions. In your case the type does change, you pass in a `tuple(int64 x 2)` but the recursive call tries to pass in a `tuple(int64 x 3)` which is a different type. Strangely it runs into a `StackOverflow` on my computer - which seems like a bug in numba.

My suggestion would be to use this (no numba, no recursion):

```
def tup(a):
    if len(a) < 5:
        a += (3, ) * (5 - len(a))
    return a
```

Which also returns the expected result:

```
>>> tup((1,))
(1, 3, 3, 3, 3)
>>> tup((1, 2))
(1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. In fact this code is not exactly what I want to run, it is just the problematic part of what I'm trying to do. the original problem is to run an arbitrary nested loop over the entries of a multidimensional array. Since the numbers of loops can vary, I was making recursive calls, each one entering in the next loop and constructing the (multi)index accordingly.

Comment: Everything would be simpler if I just passed the tuple with its final size, which I can know before starting the loop, the problem is that tuples are immutable so I can't assign the values of the indexes into them. Instead of tuples I could use arrays, and it is possible to assign new values, but I can't use an array of indexes, say [1,2,0,0,1] to access the value M[1,2,0,0,1] of a multidimensional M. Also numba doesn't let me convert an array into a tuple... I can't figure out a solution with lists either...seems each way has a little detail preventing me to do what I want to do.

Comment: Anyway, I already saw that pure python is actually faster than numba for recursion, as you've said. This is a little disappointing, I expect to gain performance since numba performs better for loops.

Comment: @Integral Not every loop can be optimized with numba, it really depends on the operations you do inside the loop.

Comment: @Integral The problem with the array - tuple conversion in numba is because tuples need to have a fixed-compile time size. Arrays don't have that size (nor do lists) so you cannot create a tuple from an array. I also found working with multi-dimensional arrays and custom indices quite complicated in numba.

Comment: I just trying creating all possible tuples with the itertools module and then could run everything in a single loop. For some reason this was much worse than the recursive approach, even with numba in nopython mode. Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: @Integral That may be better suited for a *new question* because it's too complicated to discuss this in the comments and editing this question would (likely) invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this list of proposals](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/proposals/typing_recursion.html) in the current releases:

> Recursion support in numba is currently limited to self-recursion with
>   explicit type annotation for the function. This limitation comes from
>   the inability to determine the return type of a recursive call.

So, instead try:

```
from numba import jit

@jit()
def tup(a:tuple) -> tuple:
    if len(a) == 5:
        return a

    return tup(a + (3,))

print(tup((0, 1)))
```

To see if that works any better for you.

Comment: Does that really work when you run it? I just tried to run the code and at least on my machine that just produces a StackOverflow. What's your numba version?

Comment: @MSeifert, I just went to the numba website and their "try it online" jupyter page.  It worked for me there with the annotations, but not without.  All I know.

Comment: That's interesting thanks for the explanation. But it also fails in nopython mode there.